# Instagram: is there a way to show friends' posts on my website?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Using the Instagram API or plugins (like [Instafeed](http://instafeedjs.com)) I can show logged user's photos, but I wanna show logged user's friends' photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to show any public user's photos by getting `public_content` permission for API.

If the user's friend has private profile then you cannot access via API even if the user is approved and following the friend.

You have to get your app approved by instagram for `public_content`, which you may not get if your apps purpose does not meet one of the Instagram's approved use cases: https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/